# Error while npm start for node js application : toposcache.json not found

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node js application which uses the topos package also. After performing `npm install` and then `npm start` I am getting the below error. Not sure if I am missing something.

Thanks for the help.

```
toposcache.json not found. All information will be captured in this run, and used for the next restart.
UNHANDLEDREJECTION Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open. .../node_modules/topos/topos/ports.json
```

Comment: Can you share how was this resolved

Answer (score 0):

Go to root of project and run  `rm -rf node_modules/topos` then `npm i topos`